# Какой код C# не может быть выполнен в EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Хотелось бы заранее при написании кода C# иметь понимание какой код можно написать в условиях `.Where` и других точках расширения для EF Core, а не запускать и смотреть произойдет исключение или все отработает. Сейчас представляю что код в таких лямбдах будет переведен в SQL и сразу можно догадаться что в таких условиях неправильно оставлять методы, которые будут делать запросы на внешнее API, так как такое в SQL нет возможности преобразовать.

Есть набор базовых правил? Или нужно всю документацию изучить для понимания?

Comment: Какая версия EF Core вас интересует? Они отличаются и набор костылей разный.

Comment: в приоритете последняя стабильная версия, хотя думал что преемственность значительная по этому вопросу

Comment: Смотри в [исходники](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/tree/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Internal) и для [SQL Server](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/tree/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal). `XxxTranslator.cs` содержат то что EF Core умеет транслировать

Comment: Наверно более точного ответа и быть не может, но нужно покопать немного исходники, вывести некоторое понимание как они связаны между собой.